# XML sitemap over product variations

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, seo, sitemap

So i have a smaller webshop, that contains a lot of products - and some of those products have variants - like blue, yellow, red and so on.
But the thing is that Yoast SEO's sitemap generator only indexes the main products. Lets say i have a toy car in multiple colors (white, blue, yellow, red). Yoast SEO will create a link for the default (white) toy car:

```
www.examplewebshop.com/products/toy-car
```

And thats also great, but i also want people to be able to find my red, yellow, and blue toycar.

Is their any way for me to archive this? I have been looking a little around, and seem unable to find an answer to my problem.

"My" current solution/idea, is adding parameters to the URL, and then adding it manually to the sitemap.xml. So for example:

```
www.examplewebshop.com/products/toy-car?color=blue
www.examplewebshop.com/products/toy-car?color=red    
www.examplewebshop.com/products/toy-car?color=yellow
```

*Edit
See www.hm.com/dk/product/69970#article=69970-C as an example